# Two keyboards. Can I re keymap just one?

Tags: keyboard, keymap

I have my main keyboard, and I also have an old PS/2 keyboard that I'd like to re keymap without affecting the other keyboard. What's the best way to do this?

I'm running Windows 10. My main keyboard is USB, and the other is a generic PS/2 keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a program called HID Macros. And it's exactly what I was looking for.

http://www.hidmacros.eu/

Comment: It now says *"HidMacros is dead. Welcome LuaMacros"*