# Easier way to remap keys per keyboard (multiple keyboards), on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I need more keys. Currently I have to use a lot of awkward key combinations for shortcuts like <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to rename a variable or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to format a document. My life would be a lot easier if I could just press a single key for shortcuts. There are [cheap keypads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0814K4H3D), and key remap software like [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys), but the problem is, as far as I know, the same remapping is applied to all keyboards. I don't want to remap the num1 key of my main keyboard, but only the num1 key of the separate keypad.

After some web searching, it seems that one method is creating a "custom keyboard filter driver", but that seems a hard work. I have never created a Windows device driver, and doesn't a device driver require digital signing from Microsoft? I remember that I had to put Windows into a weird test mode at the boot to load some unsigned driver. That is a lot of hassle.

Is there any other way? Or, if filter driver is the only way, isn't there a pre-made one that is already signed? I mean, all I want to do is remapping keys, so the pre-made driver could read remapping configuration from an ".ini" file.

Comment: Related: *[Remap keypad keys to media controls (HIDMacros)](https://superuser.com/questions/1112072/remap-keypad-keys-to-media-controls-hidmacros)* and *[Two keyboards. Can I re keymap just one?](https://superuser.com/questions/1198462/two-keyboards-can-i-re-keymap-just-one)*

Answer (score -2):

There is a program called [MultiKeyboard Macros](https://www.mediachance.com/multikeyboard/index.html), and I think that will help you out. It has a super friendly user interface and all the information is in the provided link.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.